# Is $\iint f(x,y)\; dx\;dy$ called an iterated integral or iterated integrals

Tags: calculus, terminology, definition, iterated-integrals

In my Calculus 4 class we are learning about finding double and triple integrals. For example, one finds a double integral
$$
\iint_E f(x,y)\;dA
$$
by writing it as 
$$
\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x,y)\; dx\;dy
$$
Is this call *an iterated integral* or is it *iterated integrals*? (So plural or singular.)

Comment: No one would get confused either way.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't think of the right tag, but terminology was what I was looking for.

Comment: @quasi: I get that, I was just wondering what technically would be the correct option.

Comment: I would choose the singular form. Of course, if you're doing several of them, then plural is correct (as in the tag).

Comment: @quasi: If you write an answer (maybe with a reference of something), I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excerpt from the text

> Stewart -- Calculus - Early Transcendentals, 6th Ed (2008)
>
> " . . . in this section we see how to express a double integral as an iterated integral, which can then be evaluated by calculating two single integrals."

Answer (score -4):

On my course that I'm creating at the minute, I usually refer to them as double or triple integrals, i.e

- Double Integral $$\iint_R dA$$
- Triple (Volume) Integral $$\iiint_V dV$$

That way, it's easier to understand, it won't scare the crap out of your students. Otherwise I'd call it an iterated integral, since it's one big integral with several parts that is. 
Hope this helps!